# Error: Authentication failed (Mongoose-encryption)

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have use mongoose encryption in other collection of the same app without problem but now that I want to use it in a new collection the documents are saved encrypted but when I try to get them I get the following error and I can not find what is the problem.

**Error message:**

```
Error: Authentication failed
at Object.schema.methods.authenticateSync (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose-encryption\lib\plugins\mongoose-encryption.js:436:19)
at model.<anonymous> (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose-encryption\lib\plugins\mongoose-encryption.js:239:47)
at Kareem.execPreSync (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\kareem\index.js:115:16)
at model.syncWrapper [as $__init] (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\kareem\index.js:232:12)
at model.Document.init (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:486:8)
at completeMany (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:41:14)
at cb (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1928:9)
at C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:75:17
at executeCallback (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:68:9)
at handleCallback (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:129:55)
at C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\to_array.js:36:13
at handleCallback (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:129:55)
at completeClose (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:859:16)
at Cursor.close (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:878:12)
at C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\to_array.js:35:25
at handleCallback (C:\Proyectos\LIMSp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\cursor.js:32:5)
```

**Schema Code:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");

const analitoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  
  nombre: String,
  abreviatura: String,
  CAS: String,
  sinonimos: [String],
  grupoSustancias: [String],
  estandarInterno: {value: Boolean, viewValue: String},
  sectores: [String],
  rubros: [String],
  habilitado: {value: Boolean, viewValue: String},
  excluido: {value: Boolean, viewValue: String},
  observaciones: String
});

var encKey = "J/zNLhysm3yMP8v24+gsCZe7dccgq4pX5bxrM6X0vHM=";
var sigKey ="ZR35/JqMv0J1V7JU+WMkV2U3HOjadPS6S6DExi2lv5v1N7S1T1I6Jm33ZSHMlnjz5qJeG0j3Qqm7ECvHMSr+Mg==";

analitoSchema.plugin(encrypt, { encryptionKey: encKey, signingKey: sigKey });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Analito", analitoSchema);
```

**Saving Schema Code:**

```
exports.save= (req, res, next) => { 
  const analito = new Analito(req.body) 
  analito.save()
  .then(documents => {       
    res.status(201).json({
      message: newSavedMessage,
      data: documents,
      error: null
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    errorHandler.errorHandler(err, res);
  })
};
```

**Get All Documents Code:**

```
exports.getAll= (req,res, next) => {
  Analito.find()
    .then((documents) => {
      filteredDocuments = documents.filter((data) =>data.excluido.value != true);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: successfullMessage,
        data: filteredDocuments,
        error: null,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => errorHandler.errorHandler(err, res));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was in the saving function.

I was passsing the req.body as an argument to when creating the new schema object.
`New Analito(req.body)`.

This worked fine if I do not encrypt data with mongoose-encryption but when encrypting data it did not work.

The solution was to pass data for each field of the Schema.

```
  const analito = new Analito({
    nombre: req.body.nombre,
    abreviatura: req.body.abreviatura,
    CAS: req.body.CAS,
    sinonimos: req.body.sinonimos,
    grupoSustancias: req.body.grupoSustancias,
    estandarInterno: {
      value: req.body.estandarInterno.value,
      viewValue: req.body.estandarInterno.viewValue
    },
    sectores: req.body.sectores,
    rubros: req.body.rubros,
    habilitado: {
      value: req.body.habilitado.value,
      viewValue: req.body.habilitado.viewValue
    },
    excluido: {
      value: req.body.excluido.value,
      viewValue: req.body.excluido.viewValue
    },
    observaciones: req.body.observaciones
  })
```